# Shortcuts for repeated template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, parameters

Let's say I have a class:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
class Foo {
};
```

in which usually `A` and `B` are the same type, but I'd like to keep the option to define `B` separately. I'd like to define an additional template, say,

```
template <typename A, typename C>
class Foo {
};
```

that is just a wrapper for `Foo<A, A, C>`. Is this common practice? If so, what's the simplest way to do it?

Comment: swapping order of `A` and `C` is not an option i guess (that would be the simplest)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 it is, if that's the only way to do it.

Comment: actually not sure if my interpreation of the question is correct. When you say "...is just a wrapper for Foo<A, A, C>" do you want `Foo<A,C>` to be the same type as `Foo<A,A,C>` or a different type? (you have an answer for either interpretation ;)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I'm not particularly interested in the type of Foo. I guess the same would be better.

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you provide more context? Why do you need this in this form? Can you abandon this order of template arguments? Do you use this in template function (so template argument detection could be used)?

Comment: Thanks for your patience @MarekR. I'm asking mostly out of curiosity, but for a bit of context: I'm writing a class that contains functions that work both with real and complex numbers. So `A` is the complex type, `B` is a necessary real type that is used to test the solutions (can't be complex), and `C` is unrelated. A common use case would be `Foo<std::complex<double>, double, int>`. When using real numbers, `A` should be the same type as `B`, so calling `Foo<double, double, int>` is redundant, and I wanted to be able to just call `Foo<double, int>` without writing additional code.

Comment: If the first type is `std::complex<double>`, can the second be anything other than `double`? If not, well, you don't actually need `B` (let's say you can derive it from `A`).

Comment: @Bob__ yes it can, for instance, you could be using `A = boost::multiprecision::mpfr_float` and `B = boost::multiprecision::mpc_complex`.

Answer (score 3):

Not the only solution, but if it is viable it is the simplest: Change order of `B` and `C` and provide a default for `B`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename A, typename C, typename B = A>
class Foo {
};


int main(){
    using Foo1 = Foo<int,double,int>;
    using Foo2 = Foo<int,double>;
    static_assert( std::is_same<Foo1, Foo2>::value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand your question this way (based on comment, question is composed with two problems, both get answered seperetly): If `A` and `B` represent same type use alternative version of template.

So looks like actually you are trying to do is [partial template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization).

Example:

```cpp
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
class Foo {
public:
    using type = B;
};

template <typename A, typename C>
class Foo<A, A, C> {
public:
    using type = C;
};
```

simple demo: https://godbolt.org/z/KPz4jj

Comment: This looks like it's what I want but when I try `print<Foo<double, float>::type>();` in your example, I get an error, when I would've expected to get `void print() [with T = float]`

Comment: To shorten arguments for templates, you need default types, but this works only on arguments at the back of list (this is shown by other answer). In your example default value is for second argument, but this can't be done (how compiler can detect that you skipped second argument?). The only way is to define typedef or type alias which will accept smaller number of arguments. Depending on you context it is also possible to leverage template argument detection, but this requires a function which receives arguments/variables.

Comment: It is possible that compilation of both answers should resolve problem, but you have to sacrifice order of template augments.